# Gremlin : fetch result as an Array

Tags: orientdb, graph-databases, gremlin

I'm trying to select the entities as mentioned in Gremlin Docs for [Select](http://gremlindocs.spmallette.documentup.com/#select)

```
gremlin> g.v(1).as('x').out('knows').as('y').select
==>[x:v[1], y:v[2]]
==>[x:v[1], y:v[4]]
```

But I'm trying to get result as like below

```
gremlin> g.v(1).as('x').out('knows').as('y').select
==>[[x:v[1]], [y:v[2],y:v[4]]]
```

Because current scenario for an entity 'x', it has more than 500 associated 'y' entities, So I'm ended up getting same 'x' data for all 'y' entities

```
gremlin> g.v(1).as('x').out('knows').as('y').select
==>[x:v[1], y:v[2]]
==>[x:v[1], y:v[4]]
==>.....
==>[x:v[1], y:v[500]]
```

Could someone guide me the way to do this?

Comment: Hi, what do you wanna to retrieve to with the query? Thx. Regards

Comment: @MichelaBonizzi I have two class 'x' and 'y'. There is a link exists between  'x' and 'y'. I want to fetch 'x' and all associated 'y' objects. As I mentioned in the question, I'm able to fetch, But I want to know I there any way to fetch all 'y' objects as an array?

Comment: Just to be clear - you linked to TinkerPop 2.x documentation. Does that mean you want an answers for TinkerPop 2.x?

Comment: @stephenmallette I don't know exactly which version I'm using. I'm running these gremlins in OrientDB console.

Comment: in orientdb 2.2.20 there's gremlin 2.6.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [groupBy()](http://gremlindocs.spmallette.documentup.com/#groupby):

```
g.V(1).groupBy{it}{it.out('knows')}.cap()
```